# how to update a textlabel when a variable is changed

Tags: c#

im kinda new to programming, and i was trying to recreate candybox (some interactive website)
in windows form application. i have a variable named candy, and a timer that every second adds one to the variable candy, i have tried putting the label.text = "candy: " + candy.ToString(); in that method and it doesnt seem to work, any one able to help?

code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int candy { get; set; }
    public int lollipop { get; set; }

    public Form1(int value, int lollipop)
    {
        this.candy = value;
        this.lollipop = lollipop;
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "candy: 0";
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button2.Visible = false;
        label2.Visible = false;

        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.TimerHandler);
        timer.Start();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        candy += 2;
        UpdateCandy(candy, lollipop);
        label2.Text = "lollipops" + lollipop.ToString();
        if (candy > 9)
        {
            button2.Enabled = true;
            button2.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (candy <= 10)
        {
            button2.Enabled = false;
        }
        candy -= 10;
        lollipop += 1;
        UpdateCandy(candy, lollipop);
        label2.Text = "lollipops" + lollipop.ToString();
        label2.Visible = true;
    }
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

    private void TimerHandler(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime start;
        TimeSpan elapsed = TimeSpan.MaxValue;


        while (elapsed.TotalSeconds > 1.0)
        {
            start = DateTime.Now;

            candy += 1;


            elapsed = DateTime.Now - start;
        }
        timer.Interval = 1000 - elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
        timer.Start();

    }

    public void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.TimerHandler);
        timer.Start();
    }
    private void UpdateCandy(int candy, int lollipop)
    {
        label1.Text = "candy: " + candy.ToString();
        label2.Text = "lollipops" + lollipop.ToString();
    }


}
```

and im using visual studio 2012 (if this information is of any help)

Comment: invalidate the form http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @N4TKD it doesnt seem to reach there(where it fails is in the TimeHandler methode, might have been helpfull if i did post that) but it doesnt seem to reach the code underneath candy += 1;

Comment: @mehow it doesnt update label1 (the one that displays candy) when the while loop from TimeHandler is being executed